# Please advise the reason I can't create group with name "con"

Tags: java, rest

Please advise the reason I can't create group with name "con" in RESTXpress. Could you take a look on this problem?
Environment: Windows7, tomcat 7, jdk 6

Answer (score 6):

On windows you can't create a file named "con", "prn", "aux", and a few other reserved words, which prevents RESTXPress from creating the related folders.

See [Microsoft's related note](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496/en-us).

Answer (score 4):

RESTXpress store groups in separate folders (group name matches folder name).
But windows doesn't allow create folder name that have "System Action" or "Device"  references such 
as con, nul and prn. 
Solution is to use another name or use 0 instead of o,O for C0n.
Here are others :
CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, 
LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9

It is known bug and they promise fix it in next release.